# Can information theory characterise a (topological) space?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, it.information-theory, combinatorial-optimization

Consider an objective function f: $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with a vector of variables $\theta$, i.e. $f(\theta)$, $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Depending on $f$, there can be interesting points such as minima, maxima, saddle points, and inflexion points.

Is there a way to characterize this network of points with information theory?

In what ways can you partition a set of **local** minima? For example, minima that have the same value for the objective function, and minima that are symmetrical, i.e. $x$ and $y$ are symmetrical if $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the [Reeb graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reeb_graph) and then deploy [The Nyquist theorem for cellular sheaves](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7212)